# Dynamic Multiselect choice values in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

There is `jenkins` **parameterized job**.

And there are two properties defined

1. Property1 of choice type (has different configurations)
2. Property2 of Extended Choice with Multi select, Choose Source for Value as Groovy script(each configuration has list of different test suites). Referring to [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) jenkins plugin.

Would like to **show the different list of values in Property2 based on the value selected for Property1.**

Tried accessing `Property1`, `$Property1`, `%Property1%` in Groovy Script of Property2. But, does not seem to work.

Script looks something like below

```groovy
if ($Property1 == 'configuration1') {
    return ['suite1','suite2', 'suite3']
} else if ($Property1 == 'configuration2') {
    return ['suite3', 'suite4']
} else if ($Property1 == 'configuration3') {
    return ['suite5', 'suite6']
}
```

Even returning simple list to `Property2` also does not seem to work from Groovy Script like `return ['suite1', 'suite2']` (just tried to show list of values without even checking condition). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Jenkins Active Choices plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin). The parameter options can be dynamically generated from a Groovy script and can respond to changes in other job parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the alternative plugin, I was using [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin which I updated the question as you type in the answer. Any idea what is the issue with above one? and accessing the one property into another property?

Comment: Any ways, am ok with the alternative, at least this allows me to do what I want.